# ошибка при вызове декоратора

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть декоратор

```
def beauty_print(func):
    def wrapper():
        print('---------------------------------------------------------------')
        func()
        print('---------------------------------------------------------------')

    return wrapper()
```

и есть класс в котором я его вызываю

```
    @beauty_print
    def info(self):
        print(f"Shop\n\tname:  {self.name}\tsquare: {self.square}")
        print(f"Goods : {' '.join(self.__goods)}")
```

возникает следующая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот весь мой код

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


def beauty_print(func):
    def wrapper():
        print('---------------------------------------------------------------')
        func()
        print('---------------------------------------------------------------')

    return wrapper()


class Shop(ABC):

    def __init__(self, name, square):
        self.__name = name
        self.__square = square

    @abstractmethod
    def info(self):
        pass

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        if name.startswith(str(r'/[a-zA-ZА-Яа-я]/')):
            self.__name = name
        else:
            print("wrong name")

    @property
    def square(self):
        return self.__square

    @square.setter
    def square(self, square):
        self.__square = square if square > 0 else print("wrong square")


class Product(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.__name = name
        self.__price = price

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        if name.startswith(str(r'/[a-zA-ZА-Яа-я]/')):
            self.__name = name
        else:
            print("wrong name")

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self.__price

    @price.setter
    def price(self, price):
        self.__price = price if price > 0 else print("wrong square")


class ProductShop(Shop, Product):
    __goods = []

    def __init__(self, shop_name, square, product_name, price):
        Shop.__init__(self, shop_name, square)
        Product.__init__(self, product_name, price)
        self.__goods.append(f'{product_name} {price}')

    @beauty_print
    def info(self):
        print(f"Shop\n\tname:  {self.name}\tsquare: {self.square}")
        print(f"Goods : {' '.join(self.__goods)}")


def main():
    ps = ProductShop("pop", 123, "it", 12)
    ps.info()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во первых, `wrapper` вызывать не надо, а во вторых, `wrapper` должен принимать любые аргументы и передавать их в `func`

```
def beauty_print(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('---------------------------------------------------------------')
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('---------------------------------------------------------------')

    return wrapper
```